# Studies on Nominative determinism (That persons name plays a role in his life)?

Tags: cognitive-science

I have found this article on Wiki on [Nominative determinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism). It's a claim that a person's name plays a role in his life, like career choices and has influence over one's character in general.

I have also read [Freakonomics](http://freakonomics.com/) where it is being argued the opposite that name has no influence (section about Winner and Looser).

Both sources are significant enough to raise a conflict.

**Is there any non-anecdotal evidence (like studies) that would confirm or reject this theory?**

Comment: This question is not answerable in its current form. First of all, it's off-topic: it's clearly described as a "hypothesis", so it's not an actual claim. Secondly, asking whether "someone can play a significant role in his life" is not going to work. It's opinion based: who decides what is significant? who decides the importance of each person?; it's too broad: what life events are we talking about? Finally, it seems to be a "nature or nurture" question - they historically don't work here, as there's little-to-no-evidence.

Comment: @Sklivvz Hi, not sure why you closed the question, but ether there are studies or not. Freakonomics is quite a known source, and if you feel my wording is not 'skeptical vocabulary' they you are welcome to change it.

Comment: [A Boy Named Sue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOHPuY88Ry4)

Comment: That Wiki page was a good read